# Haskell deducing constraints works in cabal package, but not when importing from package

Tags: haskell, cabal, type-inference, state-monad

I wrote a cabal package with a number of working examples. However, when I copy one of these examples out of the Examples directory and try to run it, I get the error below:

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal add-source deckbuild/
$ cabal install deckbuild/
$ cabal repl
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
λ> :l GreedyInference.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( GreedyInference.hs, interpreted )

GreedyInference.hs:93:27:
      Could not deduce (mtl-2.1.3.1:Control.Monad.State.Class.MonadState
                          Game (StateT Game m))
        arising from a use of ‘runGame’
      from the context (MonadState Game m, MonadIO m)
        bound by the type signature for
                   runGreedy :: (MonadState Game m, MonadIO m) =>
                                (Double, Double) -> m Game
        at GreedyInference.hs:92:14-94
      In the first argument of ‘execStateT’, namely ‘runGame’
      In the expression: execStateT runGame
      In the expression: execStateT runGame $ greedyGame ps

GreedyInference.hs:107:29:
      No instance for (MonadState Game IO)
        arising from a use of ‘runGreedy’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘runGreedy (param0, param1)’
      In the expression: unsafePerformIO $ runGreedy (param0, param1)
      In an equation for ‘g’:
          g = unsafePerformIO $ runGreedy (param0, param1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Since the type signatures work in the cabal package, I have the feeling I'm missing an import or I need to tweak the type signatures slightly when using the code from outside the package. Any ideas? I'm just looking for a push in the right direction and I should be able to figure out the specifics.

The working (when loaded with `cabal repl` from inside the package) module can be found here: https://github.com/cronburg/deckbuild/blob/master/Examples/GreedyInference.hs

EDIT: I think it has something to do with `Lazy` vs `Class` in `Control.Monad.State`. The deduce wants `Class` for some reason, but hackage says `Lazy` is the default. Which one should I be using and why?

Comment: Is `mtl-2.1.3.1` the same version of `mtl` that you used to compile your package containing actual instances for `Game`?  It looks like there's some kind of version conflict going on.

Comment: when I cabal repl inside the package: `Loading package mtl-2.1.3.1 ... linking ... done.`

Comment: But what's the version of `mtl` that is actually being used by your `GreedyInference.hs`?  (Try using `cabal repl -v`.)

Comment: Where is `Game` defined?  Is it fully inferred, or do you specify it in either of the packages?

Comment: `Game` is a record type deriving `Typeable,Eq,Ord,Show` in a module imported by `GreedyInference.hs`.

The `ghc --make ... Examples.GreedyInference` shows `mtl-2.1.3.1` when compiling inside the package. I tried `cabal repl -v` from outside the package, but it didn't say anything about `mtl`. Do I have to explicitly install `mtl` into the sandbox before I can `:l GreedyInference.hs`?

There's only one package (`deckbuild`) which I'm trying to use from a separate (external to the package) sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just making a file at `Game/Monad.hs` containing:

```
module Game.Monad (execStateT, MonadState, MonadIO) where
import Control.Monad.State
```

Then replaced my `import Control.State.Monad` with `import Game.Monad` in `GreedyInference.hs`. The file then compiled without the error.

So I think @Rufflewind in the comments was on the right track - the `mtl` types imported in my package weren't matching the `mtl` types imported by the standalone `GreedyInference.hs`. I'm still not sure why though since the versions matched and all the pertinent imports are `import Control.Monad.State`.